# How to turn verilog gate-level code to C++ tree representation?

Tags: c++, tree, verilog

> 

```
module circuit(input a1, b1, d1, d2, output OUT);

wire a, b, c, d, e, f;

NOT A(a, a1);
NOT B(b, b1);
NOT C(c, a);
NAND D(d, d1, d2);
NAND E(e, b, c);
NAND F(f, d, e);
NOT G(OUT, f);


endmodule
```

Is there any method that is able to convert the above code to tree(in the attached [the image shows the tree I want to convert to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJtqi.png))?

I don't know if there's efficient way to construct the tree, and I have searched on the net, but didn't find relative ideas.

Comment: `out = !(!(a1 && !b1) && (d1 && d2))`? There'll be some boolean simplifications but other than that I'm not sure what you're asking for?

Comment: Tree? can you be more specific, there are builtin trees in C++. You certainly could write a function evaluating the circuit given the state of wires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Verilog syntax looks similar to C++ so you could try to shoehorn it into proper C++ although I doubt it would be a good idea :-D :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

enum class Op {
  NOT, NAND
};

struct wire {
  std::vector<wire*> inputs;
  Op op;

  bool constantValue = false;

  bool evaluate() {
    if (inputs.empty()) {
      return constantValue;
    } else if (op == Op::NOT) {
      return !inputs[0]->evaluate();
    } else if (op == Op::NAND) {
      return !(inputs[0]->evaluate() && inputs[1]->evaluate());
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};

class NOT {
public:
  NOT(wire& dst, wire& src) {
    dst.op = Op::NOT;
    dst.inputs.push_back(&src);
  }
};

class NAND {
public:
  NAND(wire& dst, wire& a, wire& b) {
    dst.op = Op::NAND;
    dst.inputs.push_back(&a);
    dst.inputs.push_back(&b);
  }
};

#define module
#define endmodule
#define output
#define input
#define circuit(...) wire __VA_ARGS__
```

and then just insert the code in a C++ function.

```
int main()
{
  module circuit(input a1, b1, d1, d2, output OUT);

  wire a, b, c, d, e, f;

  NOT A(a, a1);
  NOT B(b, b1);
  NOT C(c, a);
  NAND D(d, d1, d2);
  NAND E(e, b, c);
  NAND F(f, d, e);
  NOT G(OUT, f);

  endmodule

  std::cout << "The result of OUT = " << OUT.evaluate() << std::endl;
    
  return 0;
}
```

Instances of the `wire` class will point at other `wire` instances from the `inputs` member variable, thereby forming a "tree". Is that what you ask for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to read the verilog file outside instead of pasting it in the code, is there any methods?

Comment: Yes, you can just use `#include` to include the Verilog source code in the C++ source code by referring to the filename of the Verilog file: `#include "path_to_verilog_source_code.v"`.

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't figure out how to access the tree. Additionally, is this method available to the readfile function in c++? I want to use c++ fstream to handle the verilog file. THANK YOU

Comment: What have you tried in order to solve this problem? What does your code look like?

Comment: Sorry, my main problem is that I don't know how to access the tree. The tree is in the image of question section. The leaves of the tree will be the inputs(a1, b1, d1, d2) and the root of the tree will be the output(OUT). My goal is not to evaluate the output but to construct the tree data structure of the circuit for follow-up processing. Thank you!